# How to read the contents of an OutboundJaxrsResponse in Java

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, response

I have written a service that uses Jersey.  In the last class that returns a Response object, I have:

```
Stream<Revision> revisionss = dataSourceHandler.getRevisions( .... );
StreamingOutput stream = os -> objectHistoryWorker.revisionsTransfer(revisions, os);
return Response.ok(stream).build();
```

This gets a Stream of `Revision` objects, converts the stream into a `StreamingOutput`, and then sends it out in the `Response`.

I'm trying to write an integration test to test this, and I want to see what contents are actually inside of the `Response`.  In other words, I want to know information such as

- How many `Revision` objects exist
- Does a `Revision` object contain the correct information

The issue I'm having is that it is an `OutboundJaxrsResponse`, and the `readEntity()` method is not supported for it.

It has methods that will return whether it passed or not (i.e. status code 200), but I can't seem to figure out a way to actually read the contents of the Response.

Is there a way to get that information?

(The expected response content will be in Json format)

Comment: Have you looked at https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html. You run your tests is a client-server set up which may enable you to interrogate the response that comes back from your method. Your Jersey app is run in a lightweight container and you make http requests to it if I remember correctly

Comment: `getEntity()` then cast it

Answer (score 4):

The class `org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundJaxrsResponse` **does** support `getEntity()`.

How to get the response contents as a Java String. From this, I'm sure you can work out how to read it as Json or XML ....

```
private String entity( Response response ) throws WebApplicationException, IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    StreamingOutput output = (StreamingOutput) response.getEntity();
    output.write( baos );
    return baos.toString( "UTF-8" );
}
```